# Can't uninstall xampp on windows 10 - "make sure you typed the name correctley"

Tags: xampp

Hello so im trying to delte xampp and when running the uninstall (even with `run as administrator`)

I get the following error

> Windows cannot find C:\xampp\uninstall.exe Make sure you typed the name correctley, and then try again

First of all what should i make sure i typed correcltey ? All i did was click the uninstall.exe.

Second why cant it find it ?

My xampp location is

> C:\xampp

so it should work..

Is there any way i can fore uninstall it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i figured it out.

Since the message says it can't find

> uninstall.exe

i renamed my uninstall to uninstall.exe and also my uninstall.dat file to uninstall.exe.dat

and then the uninstaller started and removed everything !!